# Batch process all files in folder with ffmpeg?

Tags: loops, unix, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a loop that will process all .mp4 (gopro clips) in a folder, and output each converted file with the same filename as the original + the _r suffix. I puzzled together the below from various sources but can't get it to work.

`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf "hflip,vflip" "${i%.*}_r.mp4"; done`

Running the above gives the following error.

`*.mp4: No such file or directory`

What have I done wrong?

Yes, I am in the correct directory, and there are .mp4 files in in place.
Ffmpeg is installed and runs correctly.
Working in Mac terminal.

Comment: So if you do `ls *.mp4` you see any output?

Comment: Thanks. This led me to the answer. It was just a stupid upper-lower case error. I had previously checked for this but had since changed a syntax error and forgot to change the casing. Lesson learnt and I will lead myself out with blushing cheeks.